# Meaning of "raise copy out of me"

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms-in-context

(From *The Wrecker* by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, Chapter XI, published 1892)

> His tone was no more gracious than his language; but when Mamie had turned upon him the soft fire of her eyes, and informed him that he was the first sea-captain she had ever met, “except captains of steamers, of course”—she so qualified the statement—and had expressed a lively sense of his courage, and perhaps implied (for I suppose the arts of ladies are the same as those of men) a modest consciousness of his good looks, our bear began insensibly to soften; and it was already part as an apology, though still with unaffected heat of temper, that he volunteered some sketch of his annoyances.
>
> “A pretty mess we've had!” said he. “Half the stores were wrong; I'll wring John Smith's neck for him some of these days. Then two newspaper beasts came down, and tried **to raise copy out of me**, till I threatened them with the first thing handy; and then some kind of missionary bug, wanting to work his passage to Raiatea or somewhere. I told him I would take him off the wharf with the butt end of my boot, and he went away cursing. This vessel's been depreciated by the look of him.”

Is this an idiom? Never heard of it. It doesn't mean *take a picture*, does it?

Comment: I'm not gonna try to look it up (it may never have had much currency), but I'd say it's pretty well certain he means the reporters were trying to "get a story" out of him. Presumably there's some contextual reason why a couple of hack journos might think they could get a good newspaper story from the guy; they want to *interview* him for their newspaper. ***Copy** = newspaper copy* (the text and pictures that make up a newspaper article, ***raise** = **obtain, create, cause to exist***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - it's something a moderately literate native speaker would know about, especially if they had been involved in, or interested in, preparing written material for publication, journalism, and so on.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: "copy" - sure. But I have my doubts about the specific usage ***to raise copy***. Maybe it's still current, but it sounds literary / Victorian to me. Especially in the sense of raising it ***from*** interaction with an important character within the story.

Comment: I can't find any other examples of "raise copy" with this sense, but it still seems the most likely interpretation, even if it's not a usual idiom.

Comment: @StuartF - one can use 'raise' to mean 'elicit', a laugh, interest, excitement, support, etc. The two words of the phrase fit together understandably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Raise is a verb meaning, in this piece, 'cause to exist'.

[Raise (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/raise)

'Copy' here is a noun meaning text in a newspaper or other printed item. A newspaper reporter trying to 'raise copy' is trying to get information from the speaker to make a news story to be printed.

> Copy (noun)   [uncountable] written material that is to be printed in
> a newspaper, magazine, etc.; news or information that can be used in a
> newspaper article or advertisement
>
> *The copy editors prepare the reporters' copy for the paper and write the headlines.*

[Copy (noun) - Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/copy_1#:%7E:text=noun-,noun,a%20copy%20of%20the%20report.)

Comment: copy is easy, it's the raise that is hard.

Comment: @Lambie - I think you just accidentally invented an aphorism, or was that the intention?

Comment: It seems to me the phrasing could have a derogatory meaning - the context implies or suggests this in my opinion.

Comment: @philphil - to say a reporter is 'raising copy' is not automatically derogatory (that is their job, after all) even if, as in this case, the speaker seems irritated by it.